# Buildfire: Check if user allowed tracking permission

Tags: buildfire

Is it possible to check if user accepted "Analytics Tracking" permission in Buildfire custom plugin?

We went through SDK documentation and did not find anything related to it.

We found following doc for tracking custom plugin events - https://sdk.buildfire.com/docs/analytics but we don't want data to be sent to Buildfire servers and would like to send it to mixpanel directly from custom plugin.

Answer (score 0):

[Segment.io](https://segment.com/) is the way to integrate custom plugin events and does support [Mixpanel integration](https://segment.com/catalog/integrations/mixpanel/), Analytics will be handled automatically to allow events to go through or not based on user preference